# Blender crash when running script bpy from python but run well in Blender's Text Editor

Tags: python, import, error, append

For last night, I can't use `bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath="/media/backup/blender/file.blend")` from python using this to run my python script

```
import bpy, os

def main(): 
    while True:
        exist = True
        try:
            srp = open("script.run", 'r')
        except FileNotFoundError:
            exist = False
            pass 
        if exist is True:
            for line in srp.readlines:
                text = bpy.data.texts.load(line)
                ctx = bpy.context.copy()
                ctx['edit_text'] = text
                bpy.ops.text.run_script(ctx)
                srp.close()
                os.remove("script.run")
main()
```

This command run in Text Editor, so I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: You've got an endless loop in there which would freeze the UI indefinitely and it looks like the custom context that you're passing into `bpy.ops.text.run_script` is invalid because it doesn't set the correct `area` etc. which results in a crash

Comment: This seems like an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  problem. Could you please describe what you're trying to do? I suspect the Python script execution that you're attempting to do could be simplified (e.g. by directly opening the script in the text editor or starting Blender from the command line with the `-P` flag).

Comment: I'm trying to execute severals scripts in the same blender instance from a python script.

Comment: You should try to `import` the scripts. Some adjustments to the `sys.path` may be necessary for the import to work, if you're not implementing an add-on that is installed into Blender.

Comment: I've tried to run it from Blender TextEditor itself, but it crash too, so I'll do as you proposed. My only interrogation is why it's stopped to work : I've change nothing in the files, so if you have an idea, I'm listening.

Comment: Actually, do a `git commit` & `git reset` seems to reset the whole Blender context, and now the script works again.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstand what Blender's context is and what it's used for. If anything changed after running these git commands then you've either modified the project or your script. The custom context you're creating will work when executing from the text editor (if your script is the one posted). Outside of the text editor you have to set the window, screen and area (or just the area of you're working with a copy of the current context).

Comment: Alright, I think that I understand better my issue. Thanks for your helpful responds.